# Locking columns in CFGRID using extjs javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to create a cfgrid (Coldfusion 9) with locked columns.
I looked at the code at http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/locking-grid.html and can see that the property I need to set is 'locked' = true...

here is the javascript code:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="headContent">
<script type="text/javascript">

function init()
{
    var myGrid = ColdFusion.Grid.getGridObject('gridData');

        //turn on the grid panel's lockable option - not sure if this is needed or not
    myGrid.lockable = true;

        //get the column model
    cm = myGrid.getColumnModel();

        //lock the first two columns in the grid 
    for(var i=0; i < 2; i++) {
        var thisid = cm.getColumnId(i);
        var thiscol = cm.getColumnById(thisid);
        thiscol.locked = true;
        //for (prop in thiscol){ document.write("object." + prop + " = " + thiscol[prop] + "<br>");}
        }

        //refresh the grid
    ColdFusion.Grid.refresh('gridData',false);
} 
</script>
</cfsavecontent>
```

I don't get any errors..but don't get my locked columns either.
I know I can affect the properties of the grid using this particular javascript code - I tried setting thiscol.sortable = false  and that did indeed grey out the ability to sort the column.

any ideas??

Comment: thanks for reformatting the code area...

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by downloading extjs 4 and creating the js code needed..

Comment: what was the issue and can you brief me. what you did.